# Why finding an undecidable proposition doesn't imply consistency, if anything is provable in an inconsistent axiomatic system?

Tags: logic, set-theory, axioms

I'm reading [these](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1nchF1fRGSY3R3rP1QmjUg7fe28tAS428/view) independent notes on the [*Lectures on the Geometric Anatomy
of Theoretical Physics*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V49i_LM8B0E&list=PLPH7f_7ZlzxTi6kS4vCmv4ZKm9u8g5yic), by Dr. Frederic P. Schuller. The first chapter is a brief summary of axiomatic systems and set theory. In page 6 the following definition is presented:

> An axiomatic system $a_1, a_2, . . . , a_n$ is said to be consistent if there exists a proposition $q$ which cannot be proven from the
> axioms.

The motivation for such definition is that since within an axiomatic system which contains a contradiction every proposition is provable, a sufficient condition for a consistent system is that there exist propositions which cannot be deduced from the axioms. Then the following theorem is announced:

> Any axiomatic system powerful enough to encode elementary arithmetic
> is either inconsistent or contains an undecidable proposition, i.e. a
> proposition that can be neither proven nor disproven within the
> system.

The Continuum hypothesis is then given as an example of an undecidable proposition within ZF.

**Why isn't the undecidability of CH proof that ZF is consistent, if, after all, it should be provable if ZF was inconsistent?**

Comment: I'm almost certain this has been asked before on this site, but: the point is that $\mathsf{ZF}$ alone can't prove that $\mathsf{CH}$ is undecidable over $\mathsf{ZF}$. Rather, $\mathsf{ZF}$ proves that *if $\mathsf{ZF}$ is consistent in the first place* then $\mathsf{CH}$ is undecidable over $\mathsf{ZF}$. So yes, undecidability implies consistency, but there's no problem here.

Comment: I highly recommend 'Godel,, Escher, Bach: An Eternal Golden Braid' for a walkthrough.